# How do I reverse match url using TimestampSigner in Django?

Tags: django

To register users in my Django web application I've created functionality which sends out a cryptographically signed link to already verified email addresses, which lets them access the user registration page. The next step is now to make sure the link expires after a set amount of time, but this turns out to be harder than expected.

Through this, I've been using the built-in Django Signer function, and now the idea is to convert this to the TimestampSigner function instead. To do this, I've read and followed the:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values

Here is my code:

in models.py:

```py
class GenerateUserRegistration(models.Model):
    signer = TimestampSigner(sep='/', salt='users.GenerateUserRegistration')

    def get_registration_url(self, pk):
        signed_pk = self.signer.sign(pk)
        domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
        path = str(reverse('register', kwargs={'signed_pk': signed_pk}))
        registration_url = 'http://{domain}{path}'.format(domain=domain, path=path)
        return registration_url
```

in views.py:

```py
def register(request, signed_pk):
    try:
        pk = GenerateUserRegistration.signer.unsign(signed_pk, max_age=30)
        confirmed = Program.objects.get(id=pk)
    except (BadSignature, GenerateUserRegistration.DoesNotExist):
        raise Http404(signed_pk)

def generate_user_registration_email(request):
...
        UserGenerator = GenerateUserRegistration()
        user_registration_url = UserGenerator.get_registration_url(pk)
        send_mail('app specific data')
...
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
        re_path(r'register/(?P<signed_pk>[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9_=-]+)/$', user_views.register,name='register'),
...
```

When running the program with the TimestampSigner instead of the Signer (where it works just like expected), it throws me the following error:

> "NoReverseMatch at /admin/generate-user-registration
>   Reverse for 'register' with keyword arguments '{'signed_pk': '1/1hUBvf/3EiPZDorfNCqovGyDjoO--9oyTQ'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['register/(?P[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9_=-]+)/$']"

This leads me to believe I somehow have to modify the url accordingly to accomodate for the TimestampSigner, but I can't find anything in the documentation, nor anywhere else, on this. What needs to be modified there for this to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression in your `urlpatterns` has to match the format of the signed string. As noted in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values), the timestamped signed string has a different format from the regular signed string; specifically, it "appends a signed timestamp to the value".

So you need to change the url pattern to match, namely:

```
r'register/(?P<signed_pk>[0-9]+/[A-Za-z0-9_=-]+/[A-Za-z0-9_=-]+)/$'
```

However, I suggest that you do not use `/` as a separator, since that character has semantic meaning within a URL. Use a [URL safe](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) character like `$`.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure I still properly understand the logic behind the formatting of the string, but your proposed solution definitely does the trick! :)

Comment: @ErikSundberg: Happy to help. The output of the signer is `[value][separator][signed value][separator][signed timestamp]`. The signed values are expressed using the [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) character set, hence the `[A-Za-z0-9_=-]+`.